# How to get array element in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a array like this `[["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"]]` in rails 3.I want to get those numbers whose type is "SWD".Please check my code below.

> payment_controller.rb

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

    def payment
        @payment=Vendor.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.js
        end

    end
    def check_type  
        if params[:commit]=="submit"
            @vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).map{|v|[v.v_catagory ,v.Receipt_No]}
            #@vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).pluck(:v_catagory)


        else
            @v_name=Vendor.where(:s_catagory => params[:payment][:s_catagory] ).pluck(:v_name)
        end
    end
end
```

@vendor_type is giving the value like this `[["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"]]`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@vendor_type = [["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"],["GOODS", "150325006sdfs"],["SWD", "150325006sdff"]]

output = []
@vendor_type.each do |i|
   if i.first == "SWD"
      output << i[1]
   end
end
puts output
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`assoc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc):

```
array = [["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"]]

array.assoc('SWD').last    
#=> "150325006"
```

Comment: @ spickermaan : after adding your line it is throwing error as "undefined methos last for nil class".

Comment: Did you change `array` to the name your variable has (probably `@vendor_type`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
▶ arr = [["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"]]
#⇒ [["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"]]
▶ arr.select { |e| e.first == 'SWD' }.map(&:last)
#⇒ ["150325006"]
```

Comment: @ mudasobwa : Your line is giving output as ["SWD","GOODS"] but i need only those numbers whose type is "SWD".

Comment: I have no clue what are you talking about. The code above returns exactly what expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> array = [["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"]]
 => [["SWD", "150325006"], ["GOODS", "150325006"]] 
> array.select{|e| e[0] == "SWD" }.map(&:last)
 => ["150325006"]
```